# Is it possible to replace Google's Nocaptcha challenge with distorted letters?

Tags: captcha

I'm using nocaptcha on a form. It is convenient, since for a lot of users the challenge is not triggered, but for the others the "select street signs/store fronts/vehicles" appears. Is it possible to make nocaptcha still try to validate user behind the scene, and if it fails to - show some other challenge, like the 2 distorted words, like the previous captcha did?

Answer (score 1):

Google retired distortion words awhile back since it only takes bots a few milliseconds to crack them wide open. [reCAPTCHA by Google](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) has a few settings for example:

[image]

So, option 2 invisible would be suitable but again this would be signs, cars, and storefront based questions, text no longer exists. It should be mentioned that bots are still able to crack reCAPTCHA v2 and only takes between 1-9 seconds.

There is also v3 available which I believe is much harder to crack than v2.